# How to transform one distribution into another using a linear transform of Mean and linear transform of Std?

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, linear, feature-scaling

I'm trying to account for a time correction between two streams of data, let's say Stream A and Stream B.  Stream A and Stream B each have different message arrival/latency characteristics.   Each stream message has an attribute (Z), and a message type (M1, M2).  The attributes are observed and generated independently of each other, and so what I've done is to go through several days of stream data, and computed the M1-M1, M1-M2, M2-M1, and M2-M2 time delta for each attribute (there are roughly 60 attributes).  I've computed the Mean and Std for each attribute and inter-message differences.

In order to "correct" for the time-delay differences in stream processing, I've regressed the Mean of each attribute and inter-message delay from Stream A against Stream B.  The R-squared is very high (0.8+ - sometimes 0.95 for M1-M1 and M2-M2 messages).  I've also regressed the Std of each attribute and inter-message delay from Stream A against Stream B, with similar results.

Now normally, I should just be able to use a linear transformation, but it turns out that the scaling factor for Mean and Std are different.

Mean(B) = C*Mean(A) + D

Std(B) = E*Std(A) + F

So I am stuck because I can't seem to express these two equations as a single equation that would properly adjust for both Mean and Std.

If I perform a scaling with C, and because C <> E, the Std is then incorrect.  And vice-versa.

So it looks like A and B are not just scaled by a simple coefficient, but have both different Means and Stds.